# Is there a way to combine behavior of SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE and SESSION_COOKIE_AGE

Tags: django, session-timeout

For security reasons I set [SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE) to true.

But, browser-length cookies (cookies that expire as soon as the user closes his or her browser) don't have a expire time, then [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) has no effects (Yes, I check it). But I want to set a logout/timeout on inactivity plus to logout on browse closing.

My question is, **What is the best way to implement inactivity timeout/logout in browser-length cookies scenario?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As you explain, SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE and SESSION_COOKIE_AGE are not compatible. When you set an expiration date to a cookie, the cookie becomes a no browser-length cookie.

In order to achieve your desired behaviour, you should **set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE as True and control expire timeout by hand**.

An elegant way to control by hand expire timeout is:

1. Create a new [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/) that control timeout.
2. Modify settings.py to enable your custom middleware (and sessions).

The **timeout custom middleware** can looks like:

```
# updated version that should work with django 1.10 middleware style
# tested up to django 2.2

import time
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import logout


class SessionIdleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if 'last_request' in request.session:
                elapsed = time.time() - request.session['last_request']
                if elapsed > settings.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT:
                    del request.session['last_request'] 
                    logout(request)
                    # flushing the complete session is an option as well!
                    # request.session.flush()  
            request.session['last_request'] = time.time()
        else:
            if 'last_request' in request.session:
                del request.session['last_request']

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

Solution for ancient Django versions (pre 1.10)

```
class timeOutMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            if 'lastRequest' in request.session:            
                elapsedTime = datetime.datetime.now() - \
                              request.session['lastRequest']
                if elapsedTime.seconds > 15*60:
                    del request.session['lastRequest'] 
                    logout(request)

            request.session['lastRequest'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        else:
            if 'lastRequest' in request.session:
                del request.session['lastRequest'] 

        return None
```

Remember enable [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) in order to store `lastRequest`.

This solution is wrote and tested be me and is now working in my site. This code has GNU license ;)

**New on django 1.6** ( ... two years later ... )

Datetime and timedelta values are only serializable if you are using the [PickleSerializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer). If not, perhaps easy solution is [translate datetime to unix timestamp and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime). Be free to post below this translation.

**Edited**

[django-session-security](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-session-security) app provides a mechanism to logout inactive authenticated users. Take a look.

Comment: I'm storing int(time.time()) in the session - seconds since epoch. Solves the serialization problem

Comment: Hi @Johan, are you so kind to improve the answer with `int(time.time() )` ?

Answer (score 0):

firefox(102.0.1) honoured the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True...opera/chrome/edge didn't. the most sure [django-session-security](https://django-session-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/full.html) with setting EXPIRE_AFTER to say 5 minutes or a value thats suitable to you.