# How to convert integer timestamp into a datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a data file containing timestamps like "1331856000000". Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of documentation for the format, so I'm not sure how the timestamp is formatted. I've tried Python's standard `datetime.fromordinal()` and `datetime.fromtimestamp()` and a few others, but nothing matches. I'm pretty sure that particular number corresponds to the current date (e.g. 2012-3-16), but not much more.

How do I convert this number to a `datetime`?

Answer (score 493, accepted):

[`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) is correct, except you are probably having timestamp in miliseconds (like in JavaScript), but `fromtimestamp()` expects Unix timestamp, in seconds.

Do it like that:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> your_timestamp = 1331856000000
>>> date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(your_timestamp / 1e3)
```

and the result is:

```
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 16, 1, 0)
```

Does it answer your question?

**EDIT**: [jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs) correctly suggested in a now-deleted comment to **use true division** by `1e3` (float `1000`). The difference is significant, if you would like to get precise results, thus I changed my answer. The difference results from the default behaviour of Python 2.x, which always returns `int` when dividing (using `/` operator) `int` by `int` (this is called *floor division*). By replacing the divisor `1000` (being an `int`) with the `1e3` divisor (being representation of `1000` as float) or with `float(1000)` (or `1000.` etc.), the division becomes *true division*. Python 2.x returns `float` when dividing `int` by `float`, `float` by `int`, `float` by `float` etc. And when there is some fractional part in the timestamp passed to `fromtimestamp()` method, this method's result also contains information about that fractional part (as the number of microseconds).

Comment: This function is dangerous, because takes you timezone into consideration. Try looking up utcfromtimestamp

Comment: @HaimBender Thanks! I feel like your comments deserve more attentions. `fromtimestamp` give you the date and time in local time
`utcfromtimestamp` gives you the date and time in UTC.

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, you can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and choose the units for yourself together with the timezone. That avoids all the comments and problems mentioned in the previous answer:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(int('1331856000000'), utc=True, unit='ms')
# Timestamp('2012-03-16 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Comment: Yes. pd.to_datetime is a really good method of pandas class. Even it allows you to specify the units and the timezone, which can be really helpful to determine the format of the timestamp. For example, whether it is a second, microsecond, or nanoseconds. The format which can be used in the unit parameters is (D, s, ms, us, ns).

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @Tadek answer

If the timestamps are in UTC timezone (a common way to store dates) you should use

```
datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()
```

If you use `fromtimestamp` it will assume the date is represented in your local timezone

Comment: This results in a naive datetime object which may later get interpreted as being in local time and not UTC.  The docs recommend using `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=timezone.utc)`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert integer seconds into string date and time this could be used:

```py
import time
time.strftime('%d:%m:%Y,%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(13318560000))
```

Output: '19:01:2392,00:00:00'