# How to use date__range filter efficiently in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

My model is

```
class SMS(models.Model):
    subscriberId = models.ForeignKey(Subscriber, null=False)
    epochTime =  models.IntegerField(null = False)
    time = models.CharField(max_length= 250 ,blank = False)
    date = models.CharField(max_length= 50 ,blank = False)
```

Now, the issue is I am saving date as a character `1-11-2015` and using `date__range` filter like this:

```
SMS.objects.filter(date__range =["1-11-2015","12-11-2015"]).count()
```

But it is giving me wrong results.

So, how to use this `date__range` filter efficiently?

Comment: just use DateTimeField insted of Char

Comment: Or perhaps `DateField`

Answer (score 0):

Well you are doing `__range` operator on a `CharField`, so the range comparison is done on a character basis not a date basis.

You already have a field `epochTime =  models.IntegerField(null = False)`, I'll assume that a UNIX time epoch.

To start soft, you can already do a `epochTime__range` query that can correctly give results if you pass in an `epochTime__range=(timestamp_integer_start, timestamp_integer_end)` range. [You'll have to pass an integer that represents the date/time for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/how-to-convert-a-python-datetime-object-to-seconds).

Otherwise you can add a `timestamp = models.DateTimeField()` and copy over the values from the `epochTime` field.

It's easy to convert from a [UNIX timestamp in integer format to a Python datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime), which you can pass in as your value for the `DateTimeField` in Django.

Bottom line is, no need to duplicate the `date` and `time` fields in your model, use a single field that represents the timestamp. I recommend `DateTimeField` because your queries will be easier in Django.