# Timestamp problem when fetching data from iforge and importing it to csv

Tags: json, python-3.x, timestamp, export-to-csv

Ok I am a python beginner who tries fetching data from iforge. However I get problem with timestamp when exporting to CSV. I think timestamp should look like this "2019-03-22 23:00:00" but instead I get 1553460483. Why is that and how to fix it so it becomes in correct format in the csv file?

```
# coding: utf-8
import json
import csv
import urllib.request
import datetime

data = json.load(request)

time = data[0]['timestamp']
price = data[0]['price']
```

data = json.load(request) contains this -

```
[{'symbol': 'EURUSD',
  'bid': 1.2345,
  'ask': 1.2399,
  'price': 1.2343,
  'timestamp': 1553460483}]
```

But since I was only interested in **price** and **timestamp** I did-

```
time = data[0]['timestamp']
price = data[0]['price']
myprice = {'Date':time,'price':price}
```

And then made csv from myprice....it works but I dont know if correct =)
Now to problem -

How to fix timestamp to show up correctly in CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to figure out what unit 'timestamp' is in. My guess would be seconds since a certain start date, so go for:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(1553460483, unit='s')

Out: Timestamp('2019-03-24 20:48:03')
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick with pandas! Many thanks! 
Any idea how to without pandas?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime