# Problem in web scraping with Beautiful Soup and urllib

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

Helllo!

I'm doing some scraping on the Premier League website and I'm running into the following problem. When I run this:

```
my_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/match/{}'.format(i)
client = urlopen(my_url)
page_html = client.read()
```

this specific part of the page_html is returned like this:

```
<div class="matchDate renderMatchDateContainer" data-kickoff="1583784000000"></div>
```

when it was supposed to be like this, as I see on the browser:

```
<div class="matchDate renderMatchDateContainer" data-kickoff="1583784000000">Mon 9 Mar 2020</div>
```

[image: You can also see it here]

as a result I cannot **scrape** the date 'Mon 9 Mar 2020'.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: what are you formatting? `.format(i)`? can you post more code

Comment: if page use JavaScript to add data then you need Selenium instead of BS and urllib because BS and urllib can't run JavaScript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert integer timestamp to Python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime)

Comment: Hi @0m3r. The `.format(i)` is just so I can acess multiple pages with a for loop. Each url would be like this: https://www.premierleague.com/match/46605

Comment: Hi @furas. I really do not know if the page uses JavaScript, but I was able to scrap lots of data using BS. I'm only struggling with the dates and times.

Comment: Hello Joe. It helps, yes. But I still do not know how to excrat the number "1583784000000".

Comment: if you have in HTML `<div ... data-kickoff="1583784000000">`  then use something like `find('div', {'data-kickoff': True})["data-kickoff"]`

Answer (score 0):

The `1583685000` of `data-kickoff=1583685000000` represents 2020/03/09, are you doing the math with JavaScript?
Why don't you try to convert this data?

```
num = 1583685000000
s = str(num)
date = int(s[0:-3])
d = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(date)
d.strftime('%d/%m/%y')
```

'09/03/20'

Comment: Hello. That is actually helpful,  I was not seeing like this, so thanks! But I do not know how to extract this number from the tag as it's not the tag's text, can you help me with that?

Comment: ```
dates = soup.find_all('div', class_='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer')
for d in dates:
   dd = d['data-kickoff']
   print(dd)
```

Comment: It worked like this: 'date = page_soup.find('div', class_='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer')['data-kickoff']', thanks a lot! But, do you know why the `page_html` doesn't come with the text like I showed in the question? When I inspect the page in the browser I can see the text (as I showed in the image) and every other part of the html comes with the text. I don't understand that. But thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm also not sure why it doesn't have value. I'm happy to help in any way I can.

Comment: @OtávioSimõesSilveira in browser you see HTML with changes made by JavaScript. But BS can't run JavaScript and it gives you HTML without changes.

Comment: All right, I'm making progress with selenium now, but still not perfect. When I get the HTML element with selenium it stil has the value inseide the class, however, when I parse it using BS it loses the value. Can I parse it with selenium?

Comment: You can also get it with selenium.
If you want to do more advanced scraping, selenium is a must.

Comment: it worked with this]:> "date = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='matchInfo']//div[@class='matchDate renderMatchDateContainer']").text" thanks guys!