# TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int' when translation from Non english to english

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to parse dates in non-English and then strip time out of it.

```
date_posted = dateparser.parse(date_posted)
print("date_posted" + str(date_posted))
date_posted = datetime.date(date_posted.year, date_posted.month, date_posted.day)
```

Date printed is:
2020-04-23 00:00:00

But it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fatima.arshad\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\envs\web_scraping\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:/Users/fatima.arshad/PycharmProjects/arabam/DailyArabamSpider.py", line 42, in parse
    date_posted = datetime.date(date_posted.year, date_posted.month, date_posted.day)
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

I tried this solution : [How to convert integer timestamp to Python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime)

But that says that datetime received int is required

Non-English date is: 20 Nisan 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess is you've probably done a

```
from datetime import datetime
```

import, so `datetime.date` refers to the `date` property on `datetime` objects.

Change your import to

```
import datetime
```

instead.