# How can i convert from IntgerField(Timestamp) to python datetime

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, python-datetime

```
unban_date = models.IntegerField()
```

This Output = All the timestamps from the database

I need it to convert to DateTime
I came up with this but it does not work as it does not take IntegarField

```
    intToParser = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(unban_date)
    parserToDate = intToParser.strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(parserToDate)
```

This is dJango Models

[image]

Comment: Why didn't you use datetime field in that case?

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert integer timestamp to Python datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime)

Comment: well, no these are all converting integers to dates, Mine is an IntegarField. They are different things. Those won't take an IntegarField, they will take an Integer or a Float.

Comment: Can you show us the code as in where are you converting this? Because urban_date will ultimately return an Integer

Comment: @TaranjeetSingh I have attached  a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i have understood you have a field **urban_date** which you want to convert to datetime and use **strftime**.

if i am getting it right then you can use **property** decorator. You can read more about this [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

For your case, something like this would work.

```
# other fields
unban_date = models.IntegerField()

@property
def parserToDate(self):
    intToParser = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(self.unban_date)
    return intToParser.strftime('%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

With this each object of DisplayRecLv will have a **parserToDAte** attribute. For checking that you verify that with

```
>>> obj = DisplayRecLv.objects.first()
>>> obj.parserToDate
# some date
```

Also i would suggest if you are not working with some legacy project then use a datetime field for urban_date itself instead of integer field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm, really appreciate the help. Also learned a lot from this. :)

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote also. It would be helpful for other users and make me earn a bit reputation on StackOverflow.