# Converting dataframe to list of tuples changes datetime.datetime to int

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have some code I wrote using Pandas which does the exact processing I want, but unfortunately is slow.  In an effort to speed up processing times, I have gone down the path of converting the dataframe to a list of tuples, where each tuple is a row in the dataframe.

I have found that the datetime.datetime objects are converted to long ints, 1622623719000000000 for example.

I need to calculate the time difference between each row, so my thought was 'ok, I'm not great at python/pandas, but I know I can do `datetime.fromtimestamp(1622623719000000000)` to get a datetime object back.

Unfortunately, `datetime.fromtimestamp(1622623719000000000)` throws `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`.

So, off to Google/SO to find a solution.  I find [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744775/how-to-convert-integer-timestamp-to-python-datetime) which shows dividing the long int by `1e3`.  I try that, but still get 'invalid argument.'

I play around with the division of the long int, and dividing by `1e9` gets me the closest to the original datetime.datetime value, but not quite.

How do I successfully convert the long int back to the correct datetime value?

Code to convert string format to datetime:

```
df.start_time = pd.to_datetime(df.report_date + " " + df.start_time)
```

Info on dataframe:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 46 entries, 0 to 45
Data columns (total 19 columns):
report_date      46 non-null object
...
...
...
start_time       46 non-null datetime64[ns]
...
...
...

dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(7), int64(1), object(10)
memory usage: 6.9+ KB
None
```

My test code:

```
print("DF start time", df.start_time[5], "is type", type(df.start_time[5]))
print("list start time", tup_list[5][7], "is type", type(tup_list[5][7]),"\n")

print("Convert long int in row tuple to datetime")
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(int(1622623719000000000/1e9)))
```

Output:

```
DF start time 2021-06-02 08:16:33 is type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
list start time 1622623719000000000 is type <class 'int'> 

Convert int in row tuple to datetime
2021-06-02 03:48:39
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, and probably should have initially went with in the first place.

I originally converted my dataframe to a list of tuples for faster row processing:

```
df.to_records(index=False).tolist()
```

Unfortunately in the conversion the values in `df.start_time` were converted from a `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` to a `<class int>`

The solution:

```
df.to_dict('records')
```

This preserved the data in `df.start_time` as `Timestamp` types:

```
'start_time': Timestamp('2021-06-02 08:16:33')
```

Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Change the dtype of your column `start_time` to convert `Timestamp` to an integer (nanoseconds):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_time': ['2021-06-02 08:16:33']}) \
       .astype({'start_time': 'datetime64'})

>>> df
           start_time
0 2021-06-02 08:16:33

>>> df['start_time'].astype(int)
0    1622621793000000000  # NOT 1622623719000000000
Name: start_time, dtype: int64

>>> pd.to_datetime(1622621793000000000)  # Right
Timestamp('2021-06-02 08:16:33')

>>> pd.to_datetime(1622623719000000000)  # Wrong
Timestamp('2021-06-02 08:48:39')
```

Comment: or maybe your indexing is not good. What are the values before and after `Timestamp('2021-06-02 08:48:39')` in your dataframe?

Comment: I copied/pasted the above code to convert the column to `astype(int)` and got `TypeError: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [int32]`.  My original code to convert from string format to datetime - `df.start_time = pd.to_datetime(df.start_time)`

Comment: Please update your code with a sample of your original dataframe and the output of `df.info()`.

Comment: Added as requested to original post.

Comment: What is your version of Python? Are you working on a 32bits machine (int32)? If you want to solve the problem, I think you should use `df['start_time'].astype(np.int64)`. I can reproduce your error with: `df['start_time'].astype(np.int32)`

Comment: Python version 3.7, 64-bit.  I used `df['start_time'].astype(np.int64)` to create the `numpy.int64`, and the conversion back to a Timestamp works when I convert `df.start_time` back to `Timestamp`.  But, to process my logic faster, I convert the df to a list of tuples via  `df.to_records(index=False).tolist()`  The issue appears to be when the df rows are converted to the list of tuples, `df.start_time` is converted from `<class 'numpy.int64'>` to `<class 'int'>`, `1622621793000000000` in the df (correct) to `1622623719000000000` in the tuple (incorrect).

Comment: Is my method not fast enough? It seems you make many operations (browsing and indexing list that can be slow.

Comment: Your process is fine, it's my processing of other data in the df that takes time.  I'm just learning Pandas, and I know the worst thing you can do is iterate through a df rows, which I'm currently doing.  I put the data into a df to get it into a workable set, and now convert it back to a list of tuples to process faster by iterating through a list.