# How do I turn variable into converted time/date?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a variable named "timestamp" and the value of it is "1617108899460", how would I turn this into this format: month/day/year, hour:minutes:seconds

I tried to do the following but I got an error:

```
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Is there any way I can do this in a simple way? Like with a module?

Comment: `timestamp / 1000`

Comment: sorry? what?????

Comment: `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")`

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744811/15385970). Your timestamp value is in milliseconds.

```py
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 1617108899460
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1e3).strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
```

This works as expected.