# How do I disable automatic session expiry update in Django?

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm developing an application in Django with some specific security requirements. One of them is to disable the default behaviour to automatically extend the expiry of sessions on activity. Yes, I want to sessions to expire unless explicitly renewed (e.g. re-login, renew token, etc. - not relevant right now).

How is this improving security? Well, a malicious user taking control over the PC of the victim will then only have access to the application with the victim authenticated for only a limited time.

Unfortunately, using [`django.contrib.sessions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/), this seems not configurable as the *modification* time of the session is being used thoroughly and in the very base of the backends (`backends/base.py`) for the server-side storage as well as in the middleware component (`middleware.py`) for the HTTP cookie. Also, the expiry is only accessible in the relative form to the modification time internally (`SessionStore._session_expiry`) as only the session *data* is being loaded into the session object. So, unless we ask the model directly (`Session.objects.get(pk=s.session_key).expire_date` - ugh, ugly), we don't know what the expire date is.

How do I implement this properly? Is this possible without reimplementing the methods `get_expiry_*` and the `process_response()` middleware function? I'd rather avoid that as I think it might break a later time in case Django gets updated.

Trying that out by setting a custom session variable to keep track of the expiry in my own terms (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025372/1254292)) seems not only redundant, but it also confuses other apps/code asking `SessionStore.get_expiry_age()` while my middleware would enforce a different expiry. Therefore, I'm considering this approach to be too low in quality for my purposes.

Am I right in my assumptions above? Should I request this as a new feature and patch it myself in the meantime?

Comment: Have you tried setting these two variables in settings file `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 7200 # 2 hours
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True` No matter if the user keeps on requesting the session will expired after two hours.

Comment: Some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267957/is-there-a-way-to-combine-behavior-of-session-expire-at-browser-close-and-sessio

Comment: @AamirAdnan Thanks for the suggestion, but this still automatically extends the expiry. As danihp says in his answer in the other comment, specifying `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` invalidates the `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` setting and makes it a regular session again, effectively.