# Django: SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE not working?

Tags: django, session

I have 'SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True' in my code that is not working as it's intended to.
Having said that I've done a lot of googling and even tried IRC #django.

`SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
 SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
 #SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 600`

I have this in my settings and no special behavior in the browser and yes I'm not using chrome, and I know that

`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = <num>`

and

`SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True`
does not work together and yeah I've deleted all previously stored cookies from the browser and done

`DELETE FROM django_session;`

but there's nothing that worked so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you testing?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9290334/842935