# SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE not working

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm trying to close the session when the user closes the browser or the tab. 
I saw that `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is supposed to do that. However it doesn't seem to work.

I have successfully implemented the `session_security` plugin (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290334/5176549)).

My settings look as follows:

```
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = 120
SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = 240
```

I've tried both with `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` set to `True`and `False`, but the session is still open when I relaunch the browser.

Any tips?